# Bad cylindrical marker recognition on 13 and 14 iPhones

Tags: iphone, focus, google-maps-markers, vuforia, cylindrical

Making a project with Vuforia's cylindrical markers. Markers are relatively small ~60mm * 15mm
It turns out a strange situation.
On the latest iPhone models (13 and 14), the marker is very poorly recognized. On models X and 11, on iPads, recognition is much better.
Visually, the problem is that when moving away or approaching, the camera's focus on the marker is lost, and the image is blurred.
Maybe someone faced a similar situation?
I would be grateful for any answers and advice :)

I'll try to stable recognize a small cylindrical marker.
Stable recognition on all distance.
iPhone(13 or 14 model) loses focus when approaching or moving away from marker.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: looks more like a problem with the auto focus control on specific devices then a problem with the Vuforia tracking engine. Probably different iOS devices have a different AutoFocus mechanism. For example iOS Pro devices with a Lidar depth sensor might use that information to drive the AF algorithm

Answer (score 0):

We've observed differences in the performance of continuous autofocus when running ARKit. By default, Vuforia Engine enables ARKit via [Vuforia Fusion](https://library.vuforia.com/environments/vuforia-fusion).

The same article references an API that allows an app to disable the Fusion feature, which on iOS devices will disable ARKit. You can use this to evaluate the performance differences in continuous autofocus between the ARKit camera and the legacy iOS camera.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to select FusionMode.\n

VuforiaConfiguration.Instance.DeviceTracker doesn't have FusionMode parameter :(

It is possible to create a class of type VuFusionProviderConfig with the necessary parameter for switching:

var config = new VuFusionProviderConfig { usePlatformFusionProvider = VuBool.FALSE };
But there is no way to add it to the Vuforia config. In the description it looks like this:

“Add a Vuforia Fusion Provider configuration to the engine config with vuEngineConfigSetAddFusionProviderConfig(DeviceTracker.FusionMode in Unity)”

Comment: Sorry, something wrong with new lines

Comment: Just checked the latest API docs. Looks like the article needs to be updated - appreciate you pointing that out. Please check [this API](https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1VuforiaApplication.html#a29896d2e8dda7868066f76b194253812) using the [VUFORIA_FUSION_ONLY enum](https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/namespaceVuforia.html#a247a4d24f56f9b41c42bbf8c78c8a554). This should disable Vuforia Engine from using the ARKit camera, and enable the legacy camera.